# Can File Manager sort or filter by file size?

Tags: file-manager

I'd like to review big files, either by sorting or filtering. Is there any way to do this in EE's File Manager? Using EE 5.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no... but maybe that will improve in EE6 (which I hear has some revisions to how CP works).

Long answer is maybe... via a custom written module that creates an alternative view of the File Manager files.

Comment: Thanks, good to hear EE6 might bring this. I'll fall back to doing sorting/filtering on the server files directly.